# How to combine Bootstrap 4 dropdown items and Vue 3 dynamic component template?

Tags: bootstrap-4, vuejs3

Since Vue-i18n doesn't work with Vue 3.0, I would like to create my own simple language dropdown switcher using the Bootstrap 4 and Vue 3.0.
I try to integrate the Vue data binding. The code can be found here:

https://codepen.io/ywiyogo/pen/QWNzPyW.

(In the codepen, the dropdown doesn't work if I click. In my browser it works)

Using the `@click="locale = lang;" I can change the locale data, and the update my dynamic component. However, the dropdown item doesn't disapear after clicking. I tried` @change="setLocale(lang)", it doesn't update my dynamic component. However, the dropdown item disappear after the selection.
What is the solution to update the `locale` data, update the component and makes the dropdown disapear?

Comment: please complete this [example](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/qBZJGMN) on codepen and give the link in order to debug it

Comment: Hi @BoussadjraBrahim thanks for the hint. I edited the question and the code is now can be found here: https://codepen.io/ywiyogo/pen/QWNzPyW.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to add jQuery & Bootstrap JS Bundle to make dropdowns work.

You you add them, your language switcher works.

Here is the fixed [Codepen](https://codepen.io/tolbxela/pen/poOPByM)

I have added the following lines:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```